# Question related to cover letter

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, business-language

I have a few queries regarding how to write a cover letter:

1. "make a real contribution as member of your team." or "make a real contribution as ***A*** member of your team."
2. "If I may be a further assistance" or " If I may be of any further assistance"
3. Should we add references before closing the letter with a signature or after ?
4. Any site or source where one can check the American English and British English versions ?

Comment: In America, references are not usually included in the cover letter or resume. The resume customarily says "References provided upon request" -- the prospective employer doesn't generally request them until they're considering hiring you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grammar answers:

"Make a real contribution as **A** member of your team"

"If I may be of **ANY** further assistance"

The other two questions are really off topic for this site.

---

IMHO references should only be mentioned in a covering letter if there is something special to say about them, otherwise in the resume.